# Excel 2013: Grouping a field in one pivot tables groups the same field in another table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

Duplicate of [Grouping a field in one pivot tables groups the same field in another table](https://superuser.com/questions/592008/grouping-a-field-in-one-pivot-tables-groups-the-same-field-in-another-table),  although the solution given there does not work in Excel 2013.

I want to have separate pivot tables so that I can filter and group the data separately in each. How can this be done?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pressing ALT+D then P should open the PivotTable/PivotChart Wizard in Excel 2013

Another alternative is to click insert at the top and then you have the option of creating your own pivot table or selecting a recommended pivot table.

Comment: using insert to create pivot tables keeps formatting between them, even on Separate worksheets.

Comment: It's not clear how your post tries to answer the question, please explain it.

Comment: The OP wanted pivot tables and mentioned a solution in a previous post which I have said should work but offered an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when creating a pivot table, Excel makes a copy of the data source in a cache, which is then the source for the Pivot tables. (BTW: that's the reason why, when changing datas in your source, it doesn't actualize the Pivot table automatically).

Normally, Excel use the same cache for all pivot tables, if it comes from the same source. Having groups of fields in a pivot, impact therefore other pivot tables with the same field.

There is a however a workaround using the PivotTable/PivotChart Wizard

- On the Microsoft Website: [how to unshare a data Cache between PivotTable reports](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Unshare-a-data-cache-between-PivotTable-reports-87188806-0c24-4d17-b2f7-9e3a4a05542b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1). Preferably the 1st method
- on [this](http://excelunplugged.com/2013/06/05/how-do-i-separate-pivottables/) Website ([How do I “separate” Pivot Tables](http://excelunplugged.com/2013/06/05/how-do-i-separate-pivottables/)), the same approach, (IMO) better described (method 1)